# sql query for month wise date between particular dates (from date and to date)

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a sql table on that table

```
event_name  location    meter_id    timestamp       
powerfail    hyd        0000123     '2016-11-23 15:03:57'
powerfail    hyd        00000123    '2016-11-24 14:03:57'
```

like this i have table i have so many records i want records monthwise i have one query please modify send as early as possible
 my query is:

```
select distinct event_name, count(event_name)
from eventlog el  
where event_name='power_failed' 
and  el.timestamp >= '2016-10-01'  
and  el.timestamp < '2016-10-30' 
group by event_name 
order by event_name desc
```

I want output like this

MONTH Name     EventName  EventCount

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Different date/time functionality.)

Comment: No need for SELECT DISTINCT here, the GROUP BY will not return any duplicates.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using (which I would guess is MySQL based on the date format).

Comment: Column timestamp's data type?

Comment: `<= '2016-10-31 24:00'`?

Comment: timestamp's datatype timestamp only

Comment: i want data october as one record november as one record like this i wnat

Comment: i want output like this

Comment: MONTHNAME   eventname  eventcount

Comment: i amusing mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    monthname(timestamp) as monthname, 
    event_name, (select count(*) from eventlog where event_name =     
    el.event_name and month(timestamp) = month(el.timestamp) and 
    year(timestamp)= year(el.timestamp)) as EventCount
from eventlog el 
where el.timestamp >= '2016-10-01' and el.timestamp < '2016-10-30' 
group by event_name, year(timestamp), month(timestamp)
```

Hope this will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In a derived table, convert the timestamp to a string, and pick its first 7 characters to get `YYYY-MM` part of it. Then `GROUP BY` the result:

```
select el.mnth, el.event_name, count(*)
from
(
    select substr(cast(timestamp as varchar(30)), 1, 7) as mnth, event_name
    from eventlog
) el
group by el.mnth, el.event_name 
order by el.event_name desc, el.mnth
```

Comment: i want eventname count month wise

Comment: Yes, and this will give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  event_name, count(event_name)
from eventlog el  
where event_name='power_failed' 
And  el.timestamp BETWEEN '2016-10-01' And   '2016-10-30' 
group by event_name 
order by event_name desc
```

Comment: this is for only one month like this i want every wonth eventname count

Comment: A `GROUP BY` is needed.

Comment: If you want to group by month , you need to uses cases.Since the timestamp column data type is timstamp you need cases and use like to compare timestamp month.However, you can have an easier solution by using the group by on timestamp field , however you need to add it in the select statement.